# HttpRequestMessage.Content is lost when it is read in a logging DelegatingHandler in ASP.Net Web API

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

When trying to an object in an Action in a Controller it sporadically seems to be null. I discovered that it is due to the `ReadAsStringAsync()` in the `SendAsync()` override of the `DelegatingHandler`. The issue is with the content. When my client sends a content body and it is read in the logger it is never read by the Controller Action Invoker (or may be somewhere in the `JsonFormatter`). I suspect the subsequent call to `Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` doesnt throw an exception but also doesnt not return the expected content body (some info is returned stating that the async read is completed).

But my problem remains since I want to read a `[FromBody]` parameter in an action and it is null when the RaceCondition of `Content.ReadStringAsync` is won by the `DelegatingHandler`. When `JsonFormatter` wins it though, I get the object but that is rare (only at service startup).

Here is my `DelegatingHandler` code:

```
public class LogHandler : DelegatingHandler
{

protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var apiRequest = new WebApiUsageRequest(request);
        WriteLog(apiRequest);
        request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            apiRequest.Content = t.Result;
            WriteLog(apiRequest);
        });

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            var apiResponse = new WebApiUsageResponse(task.Result);
            apiResponse.Content = task.Result.Content != null ? task.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result : null;
            WriteLog(apiResponse);
            return task.Result;
        });
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a clue to the solution of this issue?

Comment: Forgot to mention this is RC. I suspect the observation remains same in RTM too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is *by design*. In ASP.NET Web API the body content is treated a forward-only stream that can only be read once.

You might try utilising **ASP.NET Web API Tracing** but I haven't test it with POST request yet so I'm not sure how/if it is tracing the request body (it is tracing parameters for GET request for sure). You can read more here:

- [Tracing in ASP.NET Web API (Ron Cain)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/roncain/archive/2012/04/12/tracing-in-asp-net-web-api.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Web API Tracing Preview (Ron Cain)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/roncain/archive/2012/08/16/asp-net-web-api-tracing-preview.aspx)
- [Tracing in ASP.NET Web API (Mike Wasson)](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: Thanks. I think for my requirements I can live with not writing the content to log. However this should be a 'Point to note' for all web api developers trying to log contents and also using [FromBody] in POST Actions

Answer (score 8):

ReadAsStreamAsync method returns the body content.

```
var body = string.Empty;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result))
{
    reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    body = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Beware that the using block will close the underlying steam.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
public string SafelyReadContent(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var stream = request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
    var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return result;
}
```

@pirimoglu's answer of using a "using" block didn't work for me, since when the reader was disposed, the underlying stream was also closed.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var context = (HttpContextBase)Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"];
    context.Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    context.Request.InputStream.CopyTo(stream);
    string requestBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
}
```

Returned for me the json representation of my parameter object, so I could use it for exception handling and logging.

Found as accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901906/how-to-get-hold-of-content-that-is-already-read)

Comment: But here we can't receive request headers

Answer (score 2):

but if you use the code below in the SendAsync it works properly

```
        if (request.Content != null)
        {
            request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ContinueWith
                (
                    (task) =>
                    {

                            var xxx = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(task.Result);
                    });
        }
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken) //than call the base
```

.
.
.

Comment: That's not the same thing.  You're reading the request content not the response content, which incidentally is also why its working