# How to get HttpRequestMessage data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC API controller with the following action.

I don't understand how to read the actual data/body of the Message?

```
[HttpPost]
public void Confirmation(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var content = request.Content;
}
```

Comment: What do you get from `request.Content`?

Comment: I see all the headers and the content length, but where is the data?

Comment: You can check multiple examples here: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/How-to-Get-HttpRequestMessage-Data-in-NET-MVC

Answer (score 94, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12494758/1324019):

```
[HttpPost]
public void Confirmation(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var content = request.Content;
    string jsonContent = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

**Note:** As seen in the comments, this code could cause a deadlock and should not be used. See [this blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) for more detail.

Comment: From developer point of view, using aync may not be a better option in case if you want to debug or wait till the operation is complete to view data.

Comment: People, please read @ToddMenier's comment: DO NOT use this code in production. It's appeared in our code and has deadlocked.

Comment: Details about why this can deadlock: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: @ToddMenier no probably about it. Fact and guaranteed.

Comment: This is the wrong solution. Look at @Zebing Lin's answer

Comment: So how should this answer be edited to not cause a deadlock? Please update the answer instead of refering the reader to an external site.

Comment: @BjörnLarsson No deadlock: `var contentTask = content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Task.WaitAll(contentTask);
var content = contentTask.Result;`

Answer (score 31):

```
using System.IO;

string requestFromPost;
using( StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream) )
{
    reader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
    requestFromPost = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Request.Content is a stream. Depending on when precisely your code ran, the stream may have already been consumed.

Comment: This works for MVC, while accepted answer for Web Api only

Comment: The BaseStream.Position = 0 clued me into the fact that if the content is eaten by the framework to fill in a parameter for the HttpPost method, that the stream might be reset. Which it was. Thank you.

Comment: This worked for me as well, should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 15):

I suggest that you should not do it like this.
Action methods should be designed to be easily unit-tested. In this case, you should not access data directly from the request, because if you do it like this, when you want to unit test this code you have to construct a `HttpRequestMessage`.

You should do it like this to let MVC do all the model binding for you:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Confirmation(YOURDTO yourobj)//assume that you define YOURDTO elsewhere
{
        //your logic to process input parameters.

}
```

In case you ***do want*** to access the request. You just access the Request property of the controller (not through parameters). Like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Confirmation()
{
    var content = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

In MVC, the Request property is actually a wrapper around .NET HttpRequest  and inherit from a base class. When you need to unit test, you could also mock this object.

Comment: And in case you have HttpGet? If I use Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; it doesn't work!

Comment: @ayasha: with HttpGet, the parameters should come from query string instead of request body.

Comment: @ayasha: I have also updated the answer. Just realized it did not work before

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to cast to a class and not just a string:

```
YourClass model = await request.Content.ReadAsAsync<YourClass>();
```