# Get the content of a HttpRequestMessage without headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

I am developing an MVC `ApiController` that manages the serialization of uploaded files.

I access the content of the uploaded file with this method:

```
public class UploadController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public UploadOutcome UploadFile()
    {
        HttpContent selectFile = Request.Content;
        UploadOutcome res = null;

        //implements the serialization logic
        SerializerManager serializer = new SerializerManager();

        try
        {
            string content = selectFile.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            res = serializer.Serialize(content);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

The `Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` is a widely used solution. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12494758/1083946) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17971766/1083946).

Unfortunately the obtained `content` string contains both the content and the headers of the `HttpRequestMessage`:

**File content**

```
920-006099 ;84;65;07/03/2014 00:00;13/03/2014 23:59;10;BZ;1
RL60GQERS1/XEF;1499;1024;07/03/2014 00:00;13/03/2014 23:59;5;KV;1
```

**Content string**

```
-----------------------------11414419513108
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="selectFile"; filename="feed.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

920-006099 ;84;65;07/03/2014 00:00;13/03/2014 23:59;10;BZ;1
RL60GQERS1/XEF;1499;1024;07/03/2014 00:00;13/03/2014 23:59;5;KV;1
-----------------------------11414419513108--
```

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to get rid of the headers? In other words, I want to get the content without the headers.

Comment: You could use `HttpPostedFile` as a parameter on your method. What you get from `Content` is effectively the body. It just happens to have the headers repeated in the content, together with the file.

Comment: @Kenneth, not for Web API, which ADC is evidently using.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ReadAsMultipartAsync`:

```
var content = await selectFile.ReadAsMultipartAsync(); // You *really* ought to be using await
var body = await content.Contents.Single(x => x.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name == "\"selectFile\"").ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Your content (without the headers) will be in `body`.  To use `await`, you should change your method signature to:

```
public async Task<UploadOutcome> UploadFile()
```

Comment: Unfortunately `await` is not available in MVC4. Tags updated.

Comment: @ADC, that is not true: http://byterot.blogspot.com/2012/03/aspnet-web-api-series-part-2-async.html   If you are using *.Net 4.0*, rather than 4.5, that would be true.  In that case, my answer is the same, but you can get it synchronously like you did in your original question.