# C# Rest web service Post Parameters are always null

Tags: c#, html, web-services, server-side

I have a simple Restful C# webservice contaning, with this post function:

```
public void Post(HttpRequestMessage value) 
    {
        if (value == null) Debug.WriteLine("Post *** Request. We got null");
        Debug.WriteLine("Post Request. We got: " + value);
       
    }
```

I'm testing it using a simple HTML page containing this code

```
<form action="http://localhost:44378/api/values" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="data" value="mydata" />
      <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The Web service recieves the Post request, however it doesn't seem to get the data I send it.
I get always null.

Any clues what's going wrong and what I should change?

Thanks alot.

Comment: May I suggest you check the .NET docs as there is quite a lot I don't think you understand: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/apis and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971548/how-to-get-httprequestmessage-data - also checkout Postman for an easy way to send requests to an API

Comment: I suggest you to give the parameter same name during POST...try  HTTPRequestMessage data 
in the function parameter