# Get request body in OnActionExecuting method dotnetCore

Tags: c#, .net-core, actionfilterattribute

I have web API in .net core3.
In the filter I need to get the request body

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    string body = ReadBodyAsString(context.HttpContext.Request);
}

private string ReadBodyAsString(HttpRequest request)
{
    var initialBody = request.Body; // Workaround

    try
    {
        request.EnableBuffering();

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
        {
            string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return text;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // Workaround so MVC action will be able to read body as well
        request.Body = initialBody;
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

I get the following  error:

> Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'FileBufferingReadStream`

any help is appreciated

Comment: Rather than reading the `Body` you can read the `InputStream`. Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31644235/13268855).

Comment: the object ActionExecutingContext dont contain InputStream ActionExecutingContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream get the error: HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'InputStream' and no accessible extension method 'InputStream' @Peter Csala

Comment: `HttpContext`'s type is [HttpContextBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontextbase). Its `Request`'s type is [HttpRequestBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontextbase.request). This class does have an [InputStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequestbase.inputstream) property. They are defined in the `System.Web` whereas the `ActionExecutingContext` is defined inside the `System.Web.Mvc`.

Comment: As I mentioned I am in an ActionFilterAttribute class where I have an ActionExecutingContext object that contains HttpRequest under using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http @PeterCsala

Comment: Sorry, [you are right](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.body?view=aspnetcore-5.0), my bad.

Answer (score 0):

`StreamReader` has a [constructor overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_System_Boolean_System_Int32_System_Boolean_) that takes a Boolean value as a final parameter named `leaveOpen`.  Passing in `true` will prevent the `StreamReader` from disposing the underlying `Stream` when it is itself disposed.

Be sure to set the `...Body.Position` property to zero when done reading for possible future reads (and perhaps before you read to ensure you are reading from the start of the stream).