# ASP.NET 415 Unsupported Media Type error when HttpRequestMessage Content is touched

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a message handler for my ASP.NET Web API which I would like to read the HttpRequestMessage content, make some modifications, then set it to the modified content before passing it on. However, this results in a 415 Unsupported Media Type error even if no modifications are made. This code reproduces the problem:

```
HttpRequestMessage request = (input to handler)
String body = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
request.Content = new StringContent(body);
```

How can I touch the HttpRequestMessage content without getting a 415 error? I know content is supposed be read-once, but I am replacing it with new content. Is there a read flag which needs to be reset somewhere?

Comment: is that 451 or 415?? 451 Unavailable For Legal Reasons (Internet draft)
Defined in the internet draft "A New HTTP Status Code for Legally-restricted Resources". Intended to be used when resource access is denied for legal reasons, e.g. censorship or government-mandated blocked access. A reference to the 1953 dystopian novel Fahrenheit 451, where books are outlawed.

Comment: Ah you are correct, it is 415.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this neglected answer on a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20262394/2852699

Here is the modified code for my example.

```
HttpRequestMessage request = (input to handler)
MediaTypeHeaderValue contentType = request.Content.Headers.ContentType;
String body = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
(modify body here)
request.Content = new StringContent(body);
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = contentType;
```

This lets me read, modify, then write the content without causing any errors. The default ContentType for StringContent is "text/plain; charset=utf-8" while the ContentType I needed was "application/json; charset=UTF-8".

Answer (score 1):

while posting any data to the api please make sure to send the content-type also with the header as below:
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8;

here, data being sent is in json format and in UTF-8 format.

API needs to understand the data type and data format both in order to convert it to an appropriate data type.